# Passing bundled data to a fragment started with viewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

In Eclipse  v22.6.2  an Activity called Act1 is started with an intent.
Some data is passed as a bundle by using putExtras.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MyMain.this, Act1.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();               
bundle.putString("id", _productid);
bundle.putString("name", _productname);
bundle.putString("price", _productprice);
bundle.putString("t1", _t1);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Act1 some textViews are populated with data from the passed arguments in the bundle

```
txtpid = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtdisplaypid);
txtpname = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtdisplaypname);
txtpprice = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtdisplaypprice);
txtt1 = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtdisplayt1);
txtpid.setText(getArguments().getString("id"));
txtpname.setText(getArguments().getString("name"));
txtpprice.setText(getArguments().getString("price"));
txtt1.setText(getArguments().getString("t1"));
```

In Act1 a ViewPager using a FragmentPagerAdapter is used to start a fragment named Frag1.  No intent is used.

My two questions:
How do I pass the bundled data to Frag1?
Once Frag1 has the data, how is it accessed?

Sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is very easy.
Form a bundle to send in the calling application Act1

```
           public Bundle getDetailBundle(){

              // define variables and populate
              t1 = (i.getExtras().getString("t1"));
              t2 = (i.getExtras().getString("t2"));
              t3 = (i.getExtras().getString("t3"));
              t4 = (i.getExtras().getString("t4"));

              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

              bundle.putString("t1", t1);
              bundle.putString("t2", t2);                                         
              bundle.putString("t3", t3);
              bundle.putString("t4", t4);             

              return bundle;
       }
```

Use the bundle in the frag

```
        public String stringo;
        public Bundle bunny;

        // be sure to place the following two lines of code in or after OnCreateView or //else they will end up null.

        bunny = ((Act1) getActivity()).getDetailBundle();
        textView.setText(bunny.getString("t1"));
```